# virt-top says guests are inactive

Tags: kvm-virtualization, central-processing-unit, guest

i was searching a program to show RAM and CPU usage of my KVM guests. I found virt-top which was working yesterday very good. Today i was starting it again and it dont want to work:

```
virt-top 19:46:51 - x86_64 2/2CPU 1795MHz 5713MB
4 domains, 0 active, 0 running, 0 sleeping, 0 paused, 4 inactive D:0 O:0 X:0
CPU: 0,0%  Mem: 0 MB (0 MB by guests)

ID S RDRQ WRRQ RXBY TXBY %CPU %MEM    TIME   NAME                                                                                                                               
-                                           (105)
-                                           (106)
-                                           (107)
-                                           (109)
```

It says "4 inactive", but thats wrong. See qm list:
qm list

```
   VMID NAME                 STATUS     MEM(MB)    BOOTDISK(GB) PID       
   100 thing                running    2576              32.00 297415    
   101 somet                running    1024              32.00 78696     
   102 aaaaaa               stopped    4100              32.00 0         
   103 test                 stopped    1024              32.00 0
```

I checked my process list and virt-top isnt already running. Does somebody has a tip how to get it working again?

Or does somebody knows a other tool which output stats of all kvm guests? CPU, RAM, I/O would be nice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qm` is a proxmox command afaik, and proxmox doesn't use libvirt. `virt-top` is a libvirt tool and can only be relied upon for libvirt-managed guests (or guests of systems that use libvirt to manage guests, like oVirt or RHEV)

Comment: But how could it work yesterday? I use proxmox.

Comment: No idea, but it shouldn't have. The proxmox folks think they can deliver the same functionality using their own stuff, so you need to ask them for a tool that will provide this information. Or switch to a system that doesn't try to reinvent the wheel

Comment: I checked it again and it was my openvz containers which was shown on virt-top. Strange, on my other server virt-top shows only kvm containers and no openvz containers (there i manage kvm with libvirt). It seems virt-top give out openvz containers on proxmox.
Do you know other tools like virt-top which are done for libvirt?

Comment: I don't use proxmox, so virt-top works fine for me. There are additional APIs that plug into libvirt, but essentially the data is right there in virt-top